# Print all lines where two columns are not matching

Tags: awk

I have a tab-delimited text file with three columns. I would like to output all those lines where the first and third columns are not equal.

I tried the following command with awk but it does not work:

```
awk '$1 != $3 {print $0}' myfile.txt
```

Sample data (take spaces for tabs):

```
AAA data1 AAA
BBB data2 CCC  <== I want this line to be printed out
CCC data3 CCC
```

The output of `od -c myfile.txt`:

```
0000000   A   A   A  \t   d   a   t   a   1  \t   A   A   A  \n   B   B
0000020   B  \t   d   a   t   a   2  \t   B   B   B  \n   C   C   C  \t
0000040   d   a   t   a   3  \t   C   C   C  \n
0000052
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?  What do you get as output?  It worked correctly for me, producing `BBB data2 CCC  <== I want this line to be printed out` exactly as you wanted.  What shell are you using?  Which platform are you running on?  (I tested on archaic Linux, but I'm confident it would be OK on Mac OS X, too, and other platforms.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I get the lines printed out where the 1st and 3rd columns are equal. My file is very large. Only a fraction of lines has 1st and 3rd columns not equal.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem; your script works fine for the sample you have shown us. Perhaps you need to provide us with a sample that better represents that data that you have.

Comment: If you copy the data from the question, and the code from the question, back onto your machine, and then run it, do you get the expected output?  If so, then the problem is in the representation of the data; it is more complex than what you've shown.  If you don't get the expected output, then maybe you've managed to mess with the environment in which you're running the code.

Comment: The command outputs nothing. I am using awk version 3.1.7 on CentOS

Comment: Can you show a dump (e.g. from `od -c`) of the 3-line `myfile.txt` file?  Add it to the question, of course.  There's no obvious reason for the behaviour that you say you're seeing.  And please note, I really _did_ mean "use copy from the browser and paste into the command window: `cat > myfile.txt` and hit return; then paste; hit return if necessary; then hit 'EOF' (control-D unless you've tweaked the default settings).  Then run the `awk` script copied from the question on it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It works! I followed the steps you gave. It gives me the 2nd line (without that <=== I want this line to be printed out)

Comment: Thanks for adding the `od -c` output.  Now I _am_ bemused.  I just checked; the (archaic) Linux machine has GNU `awk` 3.1.7 too.  Since my data file had the `<===` data too, it looks slightly different; it also has blanks instead of the tabs your data has.  However, fixing both issues, then `awk` works correctly on your data for me.  Have you checked your environment for any variables that might be screwing up the default behaviour of `awk`?

Comment: Do you have a non-standard locale set?  The data you showed is valid as ISO 8859-x (e.g. 8859-15) or as UTF-8, so it is going to take something fairly outlandish to break `awk`.  This would be controlled by environment variables `LANG` and the various `LC_.*` variables.  Check with `env | grep -E 'LANG|LC_'`.  This might show some extra variables, but `LC_ALL` or `LC_CTYPE` might be revealing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the ``locale'' command output shows all variables (except LC_ALL which is empty) as en_US.utf8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91144/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-xeon).

Comment: @xeon: I've started a chat for this — please join it if you want more suggestions.  You've got something obscurely amiss in your setup; I'm curious to know what.  Or have you found a solution already?

Comment: @xeon: I've left the chat room.  I'm guessing you either found a solution or had to travel home or something.  Add a message if you want to attract my attention again, but I think that this will need to go on hold with not enough information yet.

Comment: Sorry for answering late.

Comment: @EdMorton There were important issues to deal with. Second, I am surprised that nobody posted an answer but went into endless comments (afraid to get downvoted?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to using Perl:

```
perl -ane 'print if $F[0] ne $F[2]' myfile.txt
```

Comment: This could provide clues, to determine if the issue is related to awk's handling of your input file

Comment: Yes, this command works as expected.